# Can't access data from pg_index using Foreign Data Wrapper in postgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I implement Foreign data wrapper in postgreSQL 9.3 in another postgreSQL DATABASE  as below:

```
CREATE SERVER app_db 
                   FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
                   OPTIONS (dbname 'postgres', host 'localhost');

 CREATE USER MAPPING for postgres 
                      SERVER app_db 
                      OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'XXXX');



CREATE FOREIGN TABLE location_local
              (
                     id integer,
                    name character varying
               )
             SERVER app_db OPTIONS (table_name 'location') 

SELECT * FROM location_local;
```

This all works fine as location table is in public schema. but I also want to access data from pg_catalog. When I follow the same procedure to access the data than it gives me error.

```
ERROR:  relation "public.pg_catalog.pg_index" does not exist
```

is there any way to access data from catalog using FDW or any other way?

Comment: Please show the `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` command that's related to the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`schema_name` option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html#AEN153058) in the foreign table definition:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_index (
    -- ...
)
SERVER app_db
OPTIONS (
    schema_name 'pg_catalog',
    table_name 'pg_index'
);
```

But that might won't work, because `pg_catalog` is not really a schema, but a system-catalog. If that is the case, you can still use the [`dblink` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) to run queries at a foreign database.